# Can I transfer my custom T2i focusing screen to a 60D?

Tags: canon-550d, focusing-screen, canon-60d

I'm trading up my T2i for a 60D but I have a custom focusing screen for the T2i. Anyone know if I can transfer the focusing screen to the 60D or will I need to get a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can find, the 60D has the same focusing screen as 40D and 50D, and it looks quite different from the one in the 550D (T2i) so it's not likely that it will fit:

[40D/50D custom focusing screen replacement](http://www.katzeyeoptics.com/item--Canon-40D-50D-Focusing-Screen--prod_40D.html)
[550D custom focusing screen replacement](http://www.katzeyeoptics.com/item--Canon-550D-T2i-Focusing-Screen--prod_550D.html)

According to the Canon specs, the 550D focusing screen is not replaceable, although there are third party custom replacements. The 40D/50D/60D has easily replaceable focusing screens, so there are both brand and third party custom replacements available.

Comment: I figured as much, just holding out hope that the 60D would have a similar screen seeing as its closer to the Rebel than before.